# Resizing Selection Box to Hug Chosen Text

Tags: javascript, selection

I am using Javascript to dynamically add new options to a drop down list and when the list reverts to the selected item with the arrow to the right of it to expand the list, the box containing the selected text is as wide as the widest text in the options list.

So what I would like to do is have the width of the box hug the text if you know what I mean without the redundant white space to the right of the text in the box.

Thanks a lot if anyone can help me with this :-)

Comment: I start out with the OnBlur event:

<select id="DropDownList" onBlur="fnOnBlur()">

So when the user has done their selection it is time to display their selection.

So now I need to resize the width of the selection box to match the selected text. I guess it will involve the DOM so we can do:
var sel = document.getElementById("DropDownList");
and work from there. But I am new to this kind of DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy, just remove the content of hidden options (copy it into option's title) and restore it on select focus.

Code:

```
<html><head><title>Auto size select</title>

<script>
var resized = false;

function resizeSelect(selected) {
  if (resized) return;
  var sel = document.getElementById('select');
  for (var i=0; i<sel.options.length; i++) {
    sel.options[i].title=sel.options[i].innerHTML;
    if (i!=sel.options.selectedIndex) sel.options[i].innerHTML='';
  }
  resized = true;
  sel.blur();
}

function restoreSelect() {
  if (!resized) return;
  var sel = document.getElementById('select');
  for (var i=0; i<sel.options.length; i++) {
    sel.options[i].innerHTML=sel.options[i].title;
  }  
  resized = false;
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="resizeSelect(this.selectedItem)">
<select id="select" 
  onchange="resizeSelect(this.selectedItem)"
  onblur="resizeSelect(this.selectedItem)"
  onfocus="restoreSelect()">
<option>text text</option>
<option>text text text text text</option>
<option>text text text </option>
<option>text text text text </option>
<option>text</option>
<option>text text text text text text text text text</option>
<option>text text</option>
</select>
</body></html>
```